# Нажатие клавиши вне фокуса

Tags: c++

У меня есть программа, в которой по нажатию клавиши TAB отнимается 1 от числа. Как мне сделать, чтобы я мог это делать в свёрнутом окне? Много гуглил про хуки, но не понимаю как их применить здесь. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    {
        int s = 500;
        
        while (s > 0)
        {
            if (_kbhit())
            
                switch (_getch())
                {
                
                case 9:
                
                    
                    s = s - 1;
                    std::cout << s << endl;
                    
                    
                }
 
        }
        system("C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe");
    }
 
        return 0;
 
}
```

Comment: а где в Вашем коде, код отвечающий за мониторинг нажатия клавиши tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int s = 3;
    while (s)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(9)) 
        {
            s--; 
            std::cout << s;
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
    system("C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe");

    return 0;
}
```